# CSS, get 2nd and 3rd iterations of element using nth-of-type() selector

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a list

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Is there someway to select the 2nd and 3rd elements using the `nth-of-type()` CSS selector?

For example, maybe something like this: (?)

```
li:nth-of-type(1, 2) {
   color: red;
}
```

(expected result, 1 and 2 are red. This is an example, I know that in this case I could just use set the `ul` color to red)

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is always countable elements in the suggested `div` exists, **you can do this with [`nth:child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) and its function notation** just like this:

```css
ul > li:nth-child(n+2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

---

But **if you want to use a more generic solution you can get all the child elements and then use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** to select the desired one like this:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li')

const newElements = [...elements].splice(1,2)
console.log(newElements)

newElements.forEach(element => {
    element.style.color = 'red'
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

**NOTE:** Since the return value of `querySelector` in this case is an object so you should create an array from it in order to use `splice()`.

---

But in another way, if you want to **select each individual element one by one you can do this by `nth-of-type()`**.

```css
ul > li:nth-of-type(2), 
ul > li:nth-of-type(3) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use nth-child() selector like:

```
li:nth-child(1),
li:nth-child(2){
   color: red;
}
```

nth-child-of-type() selector is used to select the child element which is of the same type as parent.

You can find more:

[nth-of-type()](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp)

[nth-child()](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)